# creating base activity with navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922641/sliding-drawer-appear-in-all-activities) answer, with the main idea is to override the `setContentView` in the `BaseActivity`, the activity that will be extended by all activity so only `BaseActivity` will have the navigation drawer.

However, my navigation is never shown (even in `BaseActivity`) after i tried to implement the answer. This is what i did :

This is the navigation drawer's xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my overrided `setContentView` (in `BaseActivity`) :

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); // Your base layout here
        actContent= (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
        //listLayout = (LinearLayout) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.listLayout);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
        //getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, listLayout, true);
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }
```

And this is my `onCreate` on `BaseActivity`, note that i use `getLayoutInflater().inflate` instead of `setContentView` :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        //mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        //mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

    }
```

And finally, i just need to extend the `BaseActivity` class and code like usual.

**UPDATE**

According to the answer, this is my WORKING overrided `setContentView` :

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); // Your base layout here
        actContent= (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.frame_container);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
        super.setContentView(mDrawerLayout);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        //super.setContentView(mDrawerLayout);
        /*getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
        super.setContentView(mDrawerLayout);*/
    }
```

Comment: Just you are inflating the drawer layout, but not attaching it to `Activity` view hierarchy. note that just inflating does not mean adding

Comment: @GopalRao sorry, what do you mean?Where should i attach it, in BaseActivity or in the activity that extends the BaseActivity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `setContentView()` like this...

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); 
    actContent = (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
    // set the drawer layout as main content view of Activity.
    setContentView(mDrawerLayout);
    // add layout of BaseActivities inside framelayout.i.e. frame_container
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your answer but the navigation drawer is still not showing in both of BaseActivity and Activity that extended it

Comment: @BlazeTama Already you have initialized `drawerLayout` in `BaseActivity`, and why are you pointing it to another instance of drawerlaout in your SubActivity? I have seen this statement `mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);` in ur sub activity

Comment: Its not in my sub activity, its in BaseActivity's onCreate & setContentView

Comment: Move all your drawer layout related operations into `setContentView()` ... don't inflate drawer layout twice. you are inflating once in setContentView() and again in `onCreate()`...

Comment: do you mean i need to move the setDrawerListener & mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle from onCreate to setContentView?

Comment: @BlazeTama Yes. Do that. and dont inflate drawer layout twice

Comment: Please see my edited question Sir, now the navigation bar is working BUT the apps dont display the view from my sub activities

Comment: @BlazeTama Do u mean, Activity not showing a `View` that is added in `FrameLayout`?

Comment: I did it! Thanks very much for your help, i have been working on this since morning

Answer (score 4):

I know this is already answered, but in case someone struggles with my specific problem:

`DrawerLayout` can only have 2 childs, `content` and the `navigationView`.
if you want to include a toolbar you should wrap this inside another layout or outside the `drawerlayout`:

```
DrawerLayout
--LinearLayout (or any other layout)
----Toolbar
----Content
--NavigationView
```

or:

```
LinearLayout (or any other layout)
--Toolbar
--DrawerLayout
----Content
----NavigationView
```