# How to implement Slider Menu instead of ListView (keeping activities)

Tags: android, listview, slider

I have an existing project using `ListView` in `MainActivity` and would like to replace this by Slider Menu keeping my existing activities.

My question is how to proceed with this implementation?
Note: I've followed many tutorials but still unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Activities instead of fragments you **must** put a NavigationDrawer in every activity.

A clean solution should be this, check it:

[Navigation Drawer to switch activities instead of fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442378/navigation-drawer-to-switch-activities-instead-of-fragments)

Comment: add it as a comment before someone down votes id as this is not an answer

Comment: I can't post comments because I have less than 50 rep ><

Comment: better remove it then because some one may downvote this

Comment: I have edited my answer because I found something similar here, check it.

Comment: Hi Grender, i thnik you can help me a lot :) is it possible for you to send me how to do via my personal mail bessem.chebbi@gmail.com ?

Comment: Ok Grender, let me check your link

Comment: It seems a little bit complicated for me (im novice)..
Will keep you posted

Comment: Can I ask you why do you want to use Activities instead of Fragments?

Comment: Because my project is ready and using Gmail Sender in activities to email in background. It was previously added into Slider Menu project (from Androidhice.com) but it not worked...

Comment: Its not difficult to convert Activities into Fragments and I think that doing that and implementing a NavigationDrawer the usual way will be more easier than creating a NavigationDrawer for each Activity.