# Cant pass a string from one activity to another

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

so i have two activities, activity 1 and activity 2 and they both extend a `BaseDraweractivity` and the `BaseDraweractivity` implements navigation drawer inturn, [somewhat like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760705/8175719). Now the problem is that i cannot pass a string from activity 1 to activity 2. Ive tried this :

In activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
 i.putExtra("user", textview.getText().toString());
 startActivity(i);
```

And in activity 2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String s = intent.getStringExtra("user");
textview1.setText(s);
```

But `textview1` in activity2 remains empty. What is wrong with it and how can i solve it?

Comment: Your code is completely correct. Just check that the textview in activity2 is viisible and also the String passed from activity1 is not empty.

Comment: Can you try getParcelableExtra instead of StringExtra?

Comment: @MrudulTora yes the textview is visible and the string passed is not empty either. I guess it has something to do with the `BaseDrawerActivity` thats in between both of em.It would be awesome if you take a look at the link i provided and see if thats the case!

Comment: In manifest, how have you defined them?

Comment: @Mustansir this is how:

`<activity android:name=".activity1"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
     </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name=".activity2"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>`

Comment: Can you try changing `launchMode` to `SingleTop` and override `onNewIntent` to receive your extras

Comment: Hey did you tried logging the the string first instead of assigning it directly to the textview

Comment: i think you should log the string first in your 2nd activity, because your code is correct. You just need to check once

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
splash = bundle.getString("user");
```